# My PNG image is interferring with my collision code and I don't know how to fix it

Tags: java, collision

```java
for (int i = 0; i < asteroidCount; i++) {
    asteroids[i].move();
    
    if (asteroids[i].getY() <= 0 || asteroids[i].getY() + asteroids[i].getAsteroidHeight() >= getHeight()) {
        asteroids[i].setYDir(-asteroids[i].getYDir());
    }
    if (asteroids[i].getX() <= 0 || asteroids[i].getX() + asteroids[i].getAsteroidWidth() >= getWidth()) {
        asteroids[i].setXDir(-asteroids[i].getXDir());
    }
    
    //Collision code for when the asteroid hits the ship
    if (ship.getX() < asteroids[i].getX() + asteroids[i].getAsteroidWidth() && ship.getX() + ship.getshipWidth() > asteroids[i].getX() && ship.getY() < asteroids[i].getY() + asteroids[i].getAsteroidHeight() &&ship.getY() + ship.getshipHeight() > asteroids[i].getY()) {
        
        //Game over, stop the timer
        t.stop();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Game Over! Asteroid hit the ship.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}        
repaint();
```

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Asteroids {
    
    //Declare fields
    private int xPos, yPos, asteroidHeight, asteroidWidth;
    private ImageIcon imgAsteroid;
    private int xDir, yDir;
    private Color c;
    private boolean useImage;

    //Create a 3rd constructor that creates a ball using an image
    public Asteroids(int x, int y, ImageIcon img) {
        xPos = x;
        yPos = y;
        imgAsteroid = img;
        asteroidWidth = img.getIconWidth();
        asteroidHeight = img.getIconHeight();
        useImage = true;
        xDir = 2; 
        yDir = 2; 
    }
    
    //Accessor methods to return the values of the fields
    public int getX() {
        return xPos;
    }
    
    public int getY() {
        return yPos;
    }
    
    public int getAsteroidWidth() {
        return asteroidWidth;
    }
    
    public int getAsteroidHeight() {
        return asteroidHeight;
    }
    
    public Image getImage() {
        return imgAsteroid.getImage();
    }
    
    //Mutator methods to change the values of fields
    public void setAsteroidWidth(int width) {
        asteroidWidth = width;
    }
    
    public void setAsteroidHeight(int height) {
        asteroidHeight = height;
    }
    
    public void setColor(Color col) { 
        c = col;
    }
    
    public void setImageIcon(ImageIcon imgAsteroids) {
        imgAsteroid = imgAsteroids;
    }
    
    public void setX(int x) {
        xPos = x;
    }
    
    public void setY(int y) {
        yPos = y;
    }
    
    public void draw(Graphics2D g2) {
        if (useImage == false) {
            g2.setColor(c);
            g2.fillOval(xPos, yPos, asteroidWidth, asteroidHeight);
        } else {
            g2.drawImage(getImage(), xPos, yPos, null);
        }
    }
    
    //Overload the move method so the parameters determine how many pixels to move
    public void move() {
        xPos += xDir;
        yPos += yDir;
    }
   
    public int getXDir() {
        return xDir;
    }

    public void setXDir(int xDir) {
        this.xDir = xDir;
    }

    public int getYDir() {
        return yDir;
    }

    public void setYDir(int yDir) {
        this.yDir = yDir;
    }
    
}
```

My PNG image is interfering with my collision code and I don't know how to fix it. When I collide with the asteroid, it is a decent amount away from the asteroid and the game. I just edited the question to give more information so that it is more easily solvable. It might be a problem with the collision code, but I'm almost certain it's a problem with the PNG image.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of when it stops? What do you mean by "decent amount away"? Are your asteroid images square? What is the type of `asteroids`?

Comment: There is so much missing from this question. We don't know how the collision code is implemented (the width and height methods), so we can't know if the issue is there. Considering you are using PNG, could there be some transparent pixels on the sides of the image?

Comment: If you use java.awt.Rectangle 's, there's already an `intersects` method.

Comment: Is the image painted at its upper left corner, but the collision code is treating the point as the center, or lower right corner, or something like that?

Comment: If you suspect it’s a problem with the PNG image, add that image to your question.  Like Joachim, I wonder if it has a significant amount of empty space in it.